# C++ GTKMM gui circular dependencies

Tags: c++, user-interface, circular-dependency, gtkmm

I have been attempting to write a GTKMM gui application in C++. In my earlier projects in Java I started by making so-called 'Screen' objects which would each contain the layout of, and objects in, different screens. So I tried that in C++ as well, I derived these different Screen objects from the `Gtk::Box` so that I could easily append them to a `Gtk::Notebook`.

However I found out that this approach results in circular dependencies, and after a lot of browsing I couldn't find people with other approaches. I currently have a screen to display data retrieved from a database, and wanted to add filters to that.

I managed to allow the swapping of screens by giving each screen a pointer to the `Gtk::Notebook` they are in, but I hit a roadblock when I couldn't figure out how to make two screens interact with each other (eg. filter the data in another screen).

The general problem appears like this:

Gui.h:

```
class Gui {
protected:
    //  Child object pointers.
    Gtk::Notebook *m_screens;
    DbConnector *m_db;

    //  Screen object pointers.
    MainScreen *m_mainScreen;
    FilterScreen *m_filterScreen;
public:
    //  Constructors & destructor.
    Gui();
    virtual ~Gui();
};
```

Gui.cpp:

```
Gui::Gui() {
    //  Create application.
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create();

    //  Db connector
    m_db = new DbConnector();

    //  Create & configure window.
    Gtk::Window m_window;
    //  Window configs.....

    //  Create notebook & screen objects.
    m_screens = new Gtk::Notebook();
    m_screens->set_show_tabs(false);
    m_mainScreen = new MainScreen(*m_screens);
    m_filterScreen = new FilterScreen(*m_screens);

    //  Add notebook to window.
    m_window.add(*m_screens);

    //Insert pages.
    m_screens->append_page(*m_mainScreen);
    m_screens->append_page(*m_filterScreen);

    //  Show all children & run app.
    m_window.show_all_children();
    app->run(m_window);
}
```

MainScreen.h:

```
class MainScreen : public Gtk::Box {
protected:
    //  Parent notebook pointer.
    Gtk::Notebook* parent;

    //  Child widgets.
    Gtk::Button m_toFilterScreenButton = Gtk::Button("To Filter Screen");

    //  Constructors & desctructor.
    MainScreen(Gtk::Notebook& par);
    virtual ~MainScreen();

    //  Methods.
    void addFilter(std::string filterText);
    void toFilterScreen();
};
```

MainScreen.cpp:

```
MainScreen::MainScreen(Gtk::Notebook& par) : parent(&par) {
    //  Build screen.
    //  Packing contents.....

    //  Configure widgets.
    //  Things like widget border width.....

    //  Signal handlers.
    m_toFilterScreenButton.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainScreen::toFilterScreen));
}

void MainScreen::addFilter(std::string filterText) {
    //  Add filter
}

void MainScreen::toFilterScreen() {
    notebook->set_current_screen(pagenum_of_filterscreen);
}
```

The problem I ran into now is when the `FilterScreen` is up, a filter is selected, and that filter should be applied to the `MainScreen`. The `FilterScreen` can't reach the `MainScreen` via the `Gui` object because that would require the screens to include `Gui.h`, which would result in a circular dependency. Trying to retrieve the `MainScreen` from the `Gtk::Notebook` returns a `Widget&`, which will tell you a `Gtk::Widget` has no function called `addFilter(std::string filterText);`.

Is anybody aware of a pattern I could use that would allow this type of behavior? So far the only option I can think of is one giant class that sets the screens using functions instead of premade objects, which would be far from optimal...

Comment: There's nothing in the shown code that results in circular dependencies. `Gui.h` only needs a forward declaration of `FilterScreen`. This is obviously not the entire code, and there could be something else in the header file that needs to be refactored, but the only thing that can be answered here is about what's shown in the question.

Comment: Wouldn't that require me to forward declare like `class FilterScreen : public Gtk::Box;`, which (at least if I remember correctly) is not possible? Otherwise it will look for a `Gtk::Widget&` to append to the notebook, not knowing `FilterScreen` will be derived from `Gtk::Box`

Comment: No, that's not how forward declarations work. Just `class FilterScreen;`. That's it.

Comment: I tried that, but then it cannot be appended to the `Gtk::Notebook` because `Gui.h` does not know it is derived from `Gtk::Box`, which is ultimately derived from `Gtk::Widget`.

Comment: Forward declarations solve the problem of recursive declaration dependencies. What happens when all classes must be defined is a completely different story. At that point, everything must be defined, and since everything was forward declared, everything can now be defined normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the advice given by [Sam Varshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik) in the comments I made a tiny example app that can handle multiple screens and switch easily. For those interested: source can be found here: [ExampleApp](https://github.com/FRMeulen/ExampleApp)